# Change attributes inside a before_save callback to pass validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have an `Organization` model with an `iv` property. If the `iv` is not set, it is randomized, but it nevertheless must be unique. The first thing that came to mind is the callback below. It does not work as `valid?` would attempt to re-validate.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :iv, uniqueness: true
  before_save :set_default_iv

  def set_default_iv
    self.iv ||= random(1000)

    ### is it possible to validate like this?
    # self.iv = random(1000) until valid?
 end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `before_validation` instead of `before_save`?

Comment: It seems to me `before_validation` serves no purpose here as it does not guarantee uniqueness, only checks if the iv was set already.

Comment: If you do it before validation, then your validator will check if it's unique. If what you are saying is that you always want something unique and no chance of a duplicate hit, you might want to look into something more like a UUID which has a much lower likely hood of having a collision than `random(1000)`.

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov: It is the job of the validator to guarantee uniqueness, but not to change the value to make it unique - rather to raise an error if it is not.  It is typically the job of the before_validation callback to use some algorithm to try to ensure that the validators will be satisfied.  Calling `valid?`, however, cannot be part of that algorithm since that would invoke the validator itself.

Comment: @PinnyM: You are right. Removing caching from assignment solved the problem. `before_validation` looked like a misnomer to me. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. I would appreciate if you you help me with caching assignment (if iv is set already and is unique it should stay as such and not get randomized).

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov, removing caching introduces a new problem - the `iv` attribute will be modified whenever validation occurs.  For this reason, you need to check if `iv` already has a value (`present?`) before setting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a UUID generator as proposed, or check the uniqueness yourself using some algorithm (example below).  But do this in a `before_validation` callback, so the validator will catch any mistakes.

```
before_validation :set_default_iv

def set_default_iv
  self.iv = random(1000) until iv.present? && !collisions_exist?
end

def collisions_exist?
  class.where({:iv => iv}).
        where(new_record? ? {} : ['id != ?', id]).exists?
end
```

Note that the performance for this algorithm will degrade as the table grows and collisions become more likely to occur.  The UUID generator is certainly the recommended approach over `random(1000)` for this reason, and because you won't need to manually check for collisions at all.